# How to select records by nth minimum/maximum value of date column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, date

I have a table as follow:

```
create table x(id int, work date);
```

this table has the following records:

```
insert into x values(1,'2017-01-01'),(2,'2017-01-01'),(3,'2017-02-02'),(4,'2017-01-15'),(5,'2017-01-15');
```

Now, I want to select the records with first, second and third date values.
My desired output would be as follows:
If I want to select record with first date value then the output would be:

```
id      work  
1     2017-01-01
```

If I select record with second date value then the output would be:

```
id      work  
 4    2017-01-15
```

Any help is appreciated in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select id, work
from (
  select id, work, row_number() over (order by work) as rn
  from x
) t
where rn = 1 -- or 2 or 3 ...
```

If you need to deal with duplicate dates, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` and use a second window function to provided numbers for each date:

```
select id, work
from (
  select id, work, 
         dense_rank() over (order by work) as rn, 
         row_number() over (partition by work order by id) as rn2
  from x
) t
where rn = 2  -- second highest date value 
  and rn2 = 1 -- first date with the second highest date value
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/VQVTB53094

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, but if we have two records with same date then the `rn=2` will select the second record with the same date.
I need to select nth-date-value i.e I want to select first date with `rn=1`, then second date with `rn=2`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE work = (SELECT DISTINCT work FROM x ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Or more simpliest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (work)
       work, id
FROM x
ORDER BY 1, 2
OFFSET 1
LIMIT 1;
```

You can choose num of element by changing offset.